# CSS HTML <a> </a> tags appearing on Nav bar

Tags: html, css

I have an issue that I have not experienced before and I am hoping to get some information on it. I have a nav bar that is displayed at the top on a webpage and for some reason when the code is run, the browser adds some a>/a> tags which cause my links to have some... disposition themselves. I am hoping to find out how to stop this from happening. Below is an example of the code.

---

### My code:

```
<nav>   
    <ul id="LevelMenu">
        <?php if($currentuser['userlevel']==0) { ?>
        <li><a href="register.html">Register New Account</a></li>
        <?php } else { 
                if($currentuser['userlevel']==1) { ?>
        <li><a href="inactive.php">Account Panel<a></li>
                <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href="user.php">Account Panel<a></li>
            <?php if($currentuser['userlevel']>2) { ?>
        <li><a href="admin.php">Administration</a></li>
            <?php }
                } ?>
        <li><a href="php/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
        <li><a href="addarticle.php" id="addarticle">Add Article</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

---

### Code on Browser:

```
    <nav>
    <ul id="LevelMenu">
                <li>
                  <a href="user.php">Account Panel</a>
                    <a></a> 
                </li>
                    <a></a>
                <li>
                    <a></a>
                  <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="admin.php">Administration</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="php/logout.php">Log Out</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="addarticle.php" id="addarticle">Add Article</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

---

### Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
<li><a href="inactive.php">Account Panel<a></li>
```

You're not closing the `<a>`, but opening a new one. Fix:

```
<li><a href="inactive.php">Account Panel</a></li>
```

Same problem with:

```
<li><a href="user.php">Account Panel<a></li>
```

Comment: omg I didn't close it, such a silly mistake. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You are Not Closing Your Anchor Tag.
Correct format would be `<a href = "" ></a>`

And You are Doing it like this:

```
  <li><a href="inactive.php">Account Panel<a></li>
```

Instead Do This:

```
  <li><a href="inactive.php">Account Panel</a></li>
```

And Same with all other Places where you are doing the same.

Refer To The [W3 Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element) for further information on anchor tag.